# Install two version of the same app, in the same device

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, build.gradle

I need to install two different version of the same app on my device to do some test. I know that it's possible changing the package but also, i read that it's possible to do it changing Manifest and Gradle with the ApplicationID. 
How can I do this? 
Thanks

Comment: package and applicationID are same

Answer (score 2):

This [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/20793/175154) on android stackexchange suggests that you can do it by changing the `package` name in the `manifest.xml`.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.original.oldversion">
```

Comment: remember to Clean & Rebuild after changing package name

Comment: This answer is very old. With gradle is not a good idea to use the manifest instead of the build.gradle since this value is overridden.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to achieve it is using gradle.
You can define 2 **flavors**, something like:

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        applicationId "com.example.flavor1"
    }
    flavor2 {
        applicationId "com.example.flavor2"
    }
}
```

Pay attention to do it with the Manifest since gradle overrides this file.

You can also define a suffix.
Something like this:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
    }
    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            applicationIdSuffix ".flavor1"
        }
        flavor2 {
            applicationIdSuffix ".flavor2"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I totally forgot about flavors. I did not test this but sounds good.